# BULK load into Oracle not working with script

Tags: oracle

I trie to load a csv file into my oracle database. i use the script below for insert. But it dosen't work. The word 'DATA' in the first line is underlined and comment as "bad syntax" --- Why?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\SCHWEIZER_DATA_TABLE.csv'
INTO TABLE PEP
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE  1 ROWS;
```

Comment: This is SQL\*Loader control file syntax; are you trying to run this 'script' from SQL\*Plus, or some other client?

Comment: @Alex Poole: I run this script in SQL Developer

Comment: You can't do that. You can run the SQL\*Loader utility, which is a separate command-line tool (and you need the full client or server install of the Oracle software; instant client doesn't include it); or you could use an external table; or use [SQL Developer's own 'import' tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/appdev.41/e55591/dialogs.htm#RPTUG41617).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [SQL*Loader control file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm) syntax. `LOAD` is not a SQL command, and you can't use that control file as a statement in SQL Developer.

You can use SQL*Loader if you have the full client or server installed on your PC - the instant client does not include it. If you can put the file on the server you could use [an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011).

But SQL Developer has its own [data import wizard](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/appdev.41/e55591/dialogs.htm#RPTUG41617) which you can use to load the data from your file.

> Use this wizard to import data into a table. For example, if you right-click the Tables node or a table name in the Connections navigator and select Import Data, you can specify the .source file (such as a spreadsheet or a delimited file) from which to import data. You create a table and import data into it, or import data into an existing table.